# Update data in Background Periodically (Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-intent, android-background

The main objective of my app is, when a button is pressed:

1. Collect data from the sensors
2. Store data in the database
3. Repeat periodically (every X seconds)

I want to have it done in background, and if the `Main Activity` is destroyed, the background progress to be still running. So if you delete the activity, I want it still running.

What I am doing right now, is having an `AlarmManager` with an `Intent Service`, to set the periodic recording of the Data, but whenever I destroy the `Activity`, as they are related, my app crashes.

I know there are different to run a background process, but none fits in mine:

- `Service`: Depends on MainThread, so if the MainActivity is destroyed,
  crashes
- `Intent Service`: The one using right now, but as far as it is
  related to AlarmManager, that is related to MainActivity, when it is
  destroyed, crashes.
- `AsyncTask`: The problem of this one, is that it is
  supposed to do one task in background and it finishes, but what I
  really want is to do it periodically until the user says to stop. So
  it's not a matter of one time thing.

Is there any other way to have a background service?
Can any of the stated before be used for my purpose?
How do you recommend me to do it?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Services comes in two forms, started services suits your scenario. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html refer

Comment: Thanks @GauravGupta. I didn't know about the started services, and finally I could solve it with a remote service  `android:process=":remote"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start service in separate process using [`android:process=":servicename"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142921/usage-of-androidprocess) in AndroidManifest.xml. If service is running in another process, it wouldn't be killed with activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Artem, finally what I made was starting a remote service `android:process=":remote"`

Comment: Nice to hear, that it helps!